# Django templates tag error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

```
def _table_(request,id,has_permissions):
    dict = {}
    dict.update(get_newdata(request,rid))
    return  render_to_response('home/_display.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'dict': dict, 'rid' : rid, 'has_permissions' : str(has_permissions)}))
```

In templates the code is as,

```
{% if has_permissions == "1" %}
<input type="button" value="Edit" id="edit" onclick="javascript:edit('{{id}}')"  style="display:inline;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
{% endif %}
```

There is a template error in `has_permissions` line. What is wrong here?
`has_permissions` has the value 1 or 0.

Comment: Please include the original error message in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Versions of Django before 1.2 do not support relational operators in `{% if %}`. Use `{% ifequal %}` or a bare `{% if %}` instead.